# Happy Numbers in COBOL

Tags: cobol

As the title implies, I'm doing a software that calculate and verify if the number inserted is a happy number (OR NOT).  In COBOL language (For reference about what a happy number is https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HappyNumber.html).

Right now, my code doesnt calculate correctly if the number is happy or not (In the program HEY = Happy and HOY = not happy :C)

My question is, what am i doing wrong in the code? All i need now is to properly detect if its happy or not. Any help is well welcome.

This is my current code:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. YOUR-PROGRAM-NAME.
       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01 num PIC 9(36).
       01 addc PIC 9(36).
       01 rem PIC 9(36).
       01 pow PIC 9(36).
       01 toast PIC 9.
       01 k PIC 999 VALUE 0.
       01 l PIC 9(36).
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       MAIN-PROCEDURE.
           DISPLAY"Escribe numero "
           ACCEPT num
           PERFORM WITH TEST AFTER UNTIL addc = 1
               MOVE 0 TO addc
               PERFORM WITH TEST AFTER UNTIL num = 0
                   DIVIDE num BY 10 GIVING num REMAINDER rem
                   MULTIPLY rem BY rem GIVING pow
                   MOVE pow TO addc
               END-PERFORM

               IF addc = 1
                   MOVE 1 TO toast
               ELSE
                   MOVE addc TO num
                   ADD 1 TO k
                   IF k = 20
                       MOVE 1 TO addc
                       MOVE 0 TO toast
                   END-IF
               END-IF
           END-PERFORM

           IF toast = 1
               DISPLAY "HEY"
           ELSE
               DISPLAY "HOY"
           END-IF
            STOP RUN.
       END PROGRAM YOUR-PROGRAM-NAME.
```

Also, as an extra question, how can i handle numbers above the maximum limit of 36? without using the equivalent of strings and chars in Cobol.

Comment: @SimonSobisch Edited, and tell me if its clear or not. Thanks.

Comment: FYI I removed your note about downvoting, at the end of your question - it has nothing to do with your question and comes off as rude. People are encouraged to vote, whether upvote or downvote, without any rule about the need for providing a comment explaining the up/downvote. That said: It's unclear, from your question, what your specific issue is. You mentioned a loop, but it's not clear what is going wrong. Please edit your question with all specifics, including an explanation of what, exactly, this app is supposed to do (e.g. don't assume people know what a "happy number" is).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks for the observation and the downvote part is not a scold or being rude, but sometimes people downvote and leave, at least i wanted to know the reason of it to edit the question (Like i did after reading your and Simon comments) and i hope its clear now.

Comment: It's definitely clear enough now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
PERFORM UNTIL num > 0
```

makes the PERFORM loop to not enter, as `num` is likely to be greater than 0. What you want to do is to execute the loop, getting all the digits from num UNTIL num is 0.

Besides,

```
MOVE pow TO addc
```

should be

```
ADD pow TO addc
```

Comment: Yes, while i was editing the question following the observation of David, i was also checking the code and i changed it to PERFORM UNTIL num = 0 and now the loop ends, but something is wrong with the loops cause it doesnt detect the nnumbers correctly

Comment: Ok, the other mistake is MOVE pow TO addc which should be ADD pow TO addc

Comment: But when you do ADD, doesnt the receiver variable also add what it have? like when ADDC = 2 and POW = 3 then make it 5, but when POW = 2 and ADDC = 5, the result will be 7? Am i a bit confused about Adding in Cobol, its my second program in this language

Comment: I believe ADD behaves like: addc = addc + pow, so yes, it would be 7

Comment: Never mind, it seems to work now, thank you soo much XD